# Polymorphism of objects through a stream in java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm writing code for a university project. We have to implement a board game to be played remotely and in multiplayer.

We are currently using the request-response pattern: the clients send the requests to the server through an IO stream and the server analyzes them and returns the correct responses.

The problem is that we have many types of requests and we are using polymorphism to understand which request is the one received:

```
/**
 * This method is only functional to polymorphism: it should never be invoked.
 * @param request
 * @return only an assertion error
 */
public ResponseMsg handleRequest(RequestMsg request) {

    throw new AssertionError("It was created a RequestMsg. This should never happen.\n"
}

/**
 * The request is to change the map. 
 * If the game is not started and the player is the first, the map will be changed and
 * a broadcast with the new map will be sent to all the players.
 * @param request: the request containing the name of the map chosen
 * @return An ack response message
 */
public ResponseMsg handleRequest(ChangeMapRequestMsg request) {

    if (game != null)
        return new InvalidRequestMsg("You can't change the map when the game is already started");

    else if (request.getToken().getPlayerNumber() != 0)
        return new InvalidRequestMsg("Only the first player can change the map");

    else {

        this.map = request.getMap();

        BroadcastMsg broadcast = new ChangedMapBroadcastMsg(request.getMap());
        publisherInterface.publish(broadcast, getLobby());

        return new AckResponseMsg("Map changed successfully");
    }
}

/**
 * Handles a chat message
 *  it sends a broadcast containing the message to all the players and an 
 *  acknowledgement to the player who sent it
 *
 * @param the chat request from the player
 * @return the acknowledgement
 */
public ResponseMsg handleRequest(SendChatRequestMsg request) {

    ChatBroadcastMsg chatBroadcast = new ChatBroadcastMsg(players.indexOf(request.getToken()), request.getMessage());
    publisherInterface.publish(chatBroadcast, getLobby());
    return new AckResponseMsg("Chat message sent.");        
}
```

The problem is that when we send the requests to the server, we need to pass them through an output stream and it will read them through an input stream. We are forced to cast them as `Object`, and thus we lose the possibility to exploit polymorphism.

How can we maintain the ability to exploit polymorphism? We'd like to not use `instanceof` to get the dynamic type of the request as our professor told us never ever to do that.

Comment: Can't you just cast the Object to the base request class (RequestMsg)? You don't need to know the specific request type.

Comment: We did that and the method that was invoked was always the generic one, while we need the specific one..

Comment: Are all these methods defined in the same class? Which class is that?

Comment: Yes, it's the class MatchController I created to manage the single games (as there are different games handled by different controllers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have polymorphic message, but your message processing is *not polymorphic*. Its just overloading.

There are ways to simplify the message processing.

Move the processing onto the message itself. Then the server can just invoke a method defined in the message base class (possibly passing the server as parameter). The method then may do the processing *or* delegate back to the *correct* method of the server.

Alternately, if the messages should have no knowledge of how they are processed, you will need to do some form of dispatch. This can be done by creating *one* handler *per* message type that all have a common interface:

```
public interface MessageHandler {
    public void process(MessageBase rawMessage);
}
```

Then you need to implement a concrete handle for every existing message type:

```
public class LoginHandler implements MessageHandler {
    public void process(MessageBase rawMessage) {
        LoginMessage msg = (LoginMessage) rawMessage;
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Message dispatching then can be done according to message class, if you create a map that associates message type with a handler:

```
private Map<Class<?>, MessageHandler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();
{
    // register every handler for every message
    handlerMap.put(LoginMessage.class, new LoginHandler());
    // ... more handlers
}

public void dispatchMessage(Message message) {
    MessageHandler handler = handlerMap.get(message.getClass());
    if (handler == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported message type");
    handler.process(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did as you suggested and moved the processing into the messages. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to check if the object being sent over the stream is an instance of a certain class and then cast the object to that class.

```
Object obj = ...; // The object sent over the stream
if(obj instanceof String) {
    String str = (String) obj; // Cast it to String
    ...
} else if(obj instanceof Integer) {
    Integer i = (Integer) obj; // Cast it to Integer
    ...
}
```

So, if I were to send a `String` object over the stream, the first if-statement would run.